# Remove Pagination for Product Category Pages WooCommerce

Tags: plugins, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to remove the pagination for product category pages when selected. There are currently 9 products per page for any given category.

I manipulated the way WooCommerce displays products to display all products in a tabular format with a header at the start of every table. Having only 9 products per page divides the table into multiple segments causing issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank You.[image: Current product display of category AC-DC Power Supply]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to display all products in same page

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {   
  // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.
  $cols = -1;
  return $cols;
}
```

Add this code to your **functions.php** file. Hope this helps.